# Get a response from a form action to a php page in a javascript string

Tags: php, javascript, forms, request

Can someone give me a javascript code to get the output of a form action with a PhP file?

Something like this:

//mywebsite:

```
 <form action="www.website1.com/Page1.php" method="get or post">

   First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>

   Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">

   </form>
```

Output of www.website1.com/Page1.php:

`Hello, I'm [fname] [lname].`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in PHP as well

```
echo "Hello, I'm ".$_POST['fname']." ".$_POST['lname'];
```

Comment: While you're at it using double quotes: `"Hello, I'm $_POST['fname']." ".$_POST['lname'];`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php

Comment: I still do not understand... That code which I wrote is correct and working

Comment: Double quotes will automatically interpret variables. You don't have to unquote them.